# Function() constructor: ReferenceError: scope is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have encounter a probably strange problem. I have a js script named `a.js`:

```
var scope = "global";
var f = new Function("return scope");
console.log(f.toString());
f();
```

When I run `nodejs a.js`, it complain:

```
ReferenceError: scope is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/tmp/test/jscripttest/b.js:2:9), <anonymous>:2:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/test/jscripttest/b.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

But when I run it interactively in `nodejs REPL` with the command `.load a.js`, it works correctly.

```
> .load a.js
> var scope = "global";
undefined
> var f = new Function("return scope");
undefined
> console.log(f.toString());
function anonymous() {
return scope
}
undefined
> f();
'global'
```

My `nodejs` version is `v4.2.6`.
So why the script works interactively, but not as the file option?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems `eval()` or `new Function(...)` runs in global scope, but above `var scope = ...` is declared in module scope when executed via `node a.js` and thus not available to `eval`. The full node.js error message even contains `at Module.load (module.js:...)`

Comment: Thank you, @le_m, I may close the problem.

Comment: Don't delete the question - it will be closed as a duplicate with a redirect to the answer - but this redirect is still useful to others who search for e.g. "Function() node.js reference error" and the like.

Comment: OK, thanks to your advice! @le_m